# Javascript code not displaying menu on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my first website and I am getting stuck with javascript interaction with my responsive navigation menu. I have developed the HTML and CSS that will allow my navigation to present correctly however when I build the javascript to toggle the menu the menu does not open or close.

The HTML and CSS presents the web page to specification prior to my hiding the menu through overflow: hidden;. Also, testing the javascript is correctly applied in the header through alert('success'); works.

I cant figure out why the open/close on click is not working, thanks in advance for feedback.

HTML

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/design.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <header>
            <a class="logo" href="/Index/Home.html" title="home page"><span>bazaar ceramics</span></a>
        </header>
        <!--navigation-->
        <a class="skip" title="skip to main content" href="#content">skip to main content</a>
        <nav title="navigation" role="navigation">
            <a class="mobile_menu" title="menu" href="#"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Index.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="home page">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="Company History">Company Background</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/company_bg.html" title="company background">Company Background</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Company_Mission.html" title="company mission">Our Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Design_Process.html" title="design process">The Design &amp; Production Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Our_Procducts.html" title="our products">Our Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Achievements.html" title="achievements">Our Achievements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Cutomers.html" title="our customers">Our Customers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="our products">Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Non_Member_Catalogue.html" title="home page">Product Catalogue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Workshop.html" title="the workshop">The Company Workshop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Process.html" title="design process">The Production Process</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="policies and forms">Policies &amp; Forms</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Privacy.html" title="privacy policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Returns.html" title="returns">Returns Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Handling.html" title="handling">Handling and Care Guide</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/FAQ.html" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Documents.html" title="important documents">Important Documents</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="HTML/Contactus/ContactUs.html" title="contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="HTML/Signin/Signin.html" title="member sign in">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: .8em;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: RGB(150, 20, 7);
    color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 25px;
}

nav ul::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

nav a.mobile_menu {
    width: 35px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(../Images/icon_menu.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top 22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: none;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81, .8);
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81);
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81, .8);
}

nav ul ul li {
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

/*top level menu text*/
nav > ul {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

nav > ul > li {
    float: left
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
    width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
nav {
        height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    }

    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav a.mobile_menu {
        display: block;
    }

    /*nav a.mobile_menu::after {
        line-height: 1.9em;
        margin: 0 0 0 35px;
        color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
        content: "Menu";
    }*/

    nav ul,
    nav ul ul,
    nav ul ul ul {
        display: block;
        position: static;
    }

    nav > ul {
        padding: 0;
    }

    nav > ul > li:first-child {
        float: none;
        margin-top: 35px;
    }

    nav > ul > li {
        float: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    nav ul li:hover {
        background: none;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 8px 10px;
        padding: 6px 15px 6px 2px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
    }

    nav ul li a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    }

    nav ul ul {
        background: none;
    }

    nav ul ul li a {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    nav ul ul ul li a {
        margin-left: 60px;
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*alert('success');*/
    $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click', function () {

        var currentNavHeight = $('nav').height();

        if (currentNavHeight < 33) {

            var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
            $('nav').animate({ 'height': newNavHeight + 'px' }, 750);

        } else {

            $('nav').animate({ 'height': '0px' }, 750);

        }

    });

});
```

Please forgive the large amount of code above, adding in the hopes of not omitting something important.

The expected outcome should be that when the screen is 800px the menu should collapse to a hamburger menu button (that part works) and then open and close on click which is not working.

Comment: `.mobile_menu` is set to display:none. How are you adding click event

Comment: Where are you adding the js code at the top? If so please move the code to bottom of the html in the footer. It is working fine on my end.

Comment: Or could you try Or try changing $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click', function () { to $(document).on('click', 'nav a.mobile_menu', function () {}) as it is working fine on my end.

Comment: At brk the initial nav 'a.mobile_menu' css at the top is display none however i have added a display block after the '@media screen and (max-width: 800px) ' further down. 

@raju forgive what will no doubt be a stupid question from me. Are you referring to the <script> tags in the head?

Comment: @KFOz please also increase the height of the nav on toggle up to $('nav').animate({ 'height': '40px' }, 750);
as the icon is not visible when menu is closed.

Comment: @Raju just saw that, thank you, i also observed that the menu does not open quite far enough to see all the menu list so i have adjusted the js to solve for that as well, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you might want to make the anchor a bit more visible, instead of `<a class="mobile_menu" title="menu" href="#"></a>`, you could add some text to the anchor: `<a class="mobile_menu" title="menu" href="#">Sample text</a>`. Here you can see your code works just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*alert('success');*/
  $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click', function() {

    var currentNavHeight = $('nav').height();

    if (currentNavHeight < 33) {

      var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
      $('nav').animate({
        'height': newNavHeight + 'px'
      }, 750);

    } else {

      $('nav').animate({
        'height': '0px'
      }, 750);

    }

  });

});
```

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: .8em;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: RGB(150, 20, 7);
  color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 25px;
}

nav ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav a.mobile_menu {
  width: 35px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url(../Images/icon_menu.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top 22px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81, .8);
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81);
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: RGB(181, 89, 81, .8);
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}


/*top level menu text*/

nav>ul {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
  }
  nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  nav a.mobile_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  /*nav a.mobile_menu::after {
  line-height: 1.9em;
  margin: 0 0 0 35px;
  color: RGB(250, 245, 239);
  content: "Menu";
}*/
  nav ul,
  nav ul ul,
  nav ul ul ul {
    display: block;
    position: static;
  }
  nav>ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav>ul>li:first-child {
    float: none;
    margin-top: 35px;
  }
  nav>ul>li {
    float: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li:hover {
    background: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 10px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  }
  nav ul ul {
    background: none;
  }
  nav ul ul li a {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li a {
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <header>
    <a class="logo" href="/Index/Home.html" title="home page"><span>bazaar ceramics</span></a>
  </header>
  <!--navigation-->
  <a class="skip" title="skip to main content" href="#content">skip to main content</a>
  <nav title="navigation" role="navigation">
    <a class="mobile_menu" title="menu" href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Index.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="home page">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="Company History">Company Background</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/company_bg.html" title="company background">Company Background</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Company_Mission.html" title="company mission">Our Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Design_Process.html" title="design process">The Design &amp; Production Process</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Our_Procducts.html" title="our products">Our Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Achievements.html" title="achievements">Our Achievements</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Company/Company/Cutomers.html" title="our customers">Our Customers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="our products">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Non_Member_Catalogue.html" title="home page">Product Catalogue</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Workshop.html" title="the workshop">The Company Workshop</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Products/Products/Process.html" title="design process">The Production Process</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies.html" aria-haspopup="true" title="policies and forms">Policies &amp; Forms</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Privacy.html" title="privacy policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Returns.html" title="returns">Returns Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Handling.html" title="handling">Handling and Care Guide</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/FAQ.html" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="HTML/Policies/Policies/Documents.html" title="important documents">Important Documents</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="HTML/Contactus/ContactUs.html" title="contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="HTML/Signin/Signin.html" title="member sign in">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: @barrosey thanks, the run code snippet works... that's the first time i have seen my menu actually work...

i cant seem to get this working in any browser on my desktop though... i know this is going to sound dumb but how do i test in firefox, safari or chrome to get this working?

it seems that everyone's comments are that this works, just not for me so far...

Comment: it was the script tag... i was using a file stored on my desktop and linking to that. once i swapped out to your script tag it worked. thank you :-)

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code is correct but your code line

is not working.
Instead of this
use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*alert('success');*/
$('nav').on('click', function () {

    var currentNavHeight = $('nav').height();

    if (currentNavHeight < 33) {

        var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
        $('nav').animate({ 'height': newNavHeight + 'px' }, 750);

    } else {

        $('nav').animate({ 'height': '0px' }, 750);

    }

});
```

});

In this code by click on nav bar it works open and close.

Comment: Instead on clicking <a class="menu.item></a> u can do by this